# How to add/remove an element to/from the array in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have an array containing some elements, but I want to push new items to the beginning of the array; How do I do that?

Comment: [here's a stackoverflow.com answer with 1100+ upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951523/52074): `ARRAY+=('foo')`

Answer (score 140):

#### To add an element to the beginning of an array use.

```
arr=("new_element" "${arr[@]}")
```

Generally, you would do.

```
arr=("new_element1" "new_element2" "..." "new_elementN" "${arr[@]}")
```

#### To add an element to the end of an array use.

```
arr=( "${arr[@]}" "new_element" )
```

Or instead

```
arr+=( "new_element" )
```

Generally, you would do.

```
arr=( "${arr[@]}" "new_element1" "new_element2" "..." "new_elementN") #Or
arr+=( "new_element1" "new_element2" "..." "new_elementN" )
```

#### To add an element to specific index of an array use.

Let's say we want to add an element to the position of Index2 *arr[2]*, we would actually do merge on below sub-arrays:

1. Get all elements before Index position2 *arr[0]* and *arr[1]*;
2. Add an element to the array;
3. Get all elements with Index position2 to the last *arr[2]*, *arr[3]*, ....

   ```
   arr=( "${arr[@]:0:2}" "new_element" "${arr[@]:2}" )
   ```

#### Removing an element from the array

In addition to removing an element from an array (let's say element #3), we need to concatenate two sub-arrays. The first sub-array will hold the elements before element #3 and the second sub-array will contain the elements after element #3.

```
arr=( "${arr[@]:0:2}" "${arr[@]:3}" )
```

- `${arr[@]:0:2}` will get two elements *arr[0]* and *arr[1]* starts from the beginning of the array.
- `${arr[@]:3}` will get all elements from index3 *arr[3]*  to the last.

  one possible handy way to re-build the arr excluding element#3 (arr[2]) from that:

  ```
  del_element=3; arr=( "${arr[@]:0:$((del_element-1))}" "${arr[@]:$del_element}" )
  ```

  specify which element you want to exclude in `del_element=`.

Another possibility to remove an element is

1. Using `unset` (actually assign 'null' value to the element)

   ```
   unset -v 'arr[2]'
   ```
2. Use replace pattern if you know the value of your array elements to truncate their value (replace with empty string).

   ```
   arr=( "${arr[@]/PATTERN/}" )
   ```

#### Print the array

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: `del_element` in the removing example maybe should be better 0-based (index of first item=0 not 1). So better `arr=( "${arr[@]:0:$del_element}" "${arr[@]:$del_element+1}" )`.

Comment: When using regex, I think the value is replaced with a space  rather than an empty string

Comment: @Sadmi here it's replacing with empty string, but if you wish to replace with space or other strings/characters you also can.

Comment: Ok I got the reason, I was replacing in a string rather than the array I was using "${TESTS[@]/$del_element}" which is different from ${TESTS[@]/$del_element}

Answer (score 6):

Note that arrays in `bash` (copied from ksh) are rather associative arrays (with keys limited to positive integers also called *sparse arrays*).

```
a=(newvalue "$a[@]")
```

would make a new `$a` array with `newvalue` as `${a[0]}` and the elements of the original array appended in the numerical order of their key with keys 1, 2...

For instance, if you had:

```
bash-4.4$ typeset -p a
declare -a a=([0]="foo" [12]="bar")
bash-4.4$ a=(newvalue "${a[@]}")
bash-4.4$ typeset -p a
declare -a a=([0]="newvalue" [1]="foo" [2]="bar")
```

That explains why there's no builtin operator for that.

If you wanted to insert the `newvalue` as `${a[0]}` and shift all the other keys by one, you'd need a temporary array:

```
b=newvalue
for k in "${!a[@]}"; do
  b[k+1]=${a[k]}
done
unset a
for k in "${!b[@]}"; do
  a[k]=${b[k]}
done
unset b
```

Shells like `zsh` or `yash` that have normal arrays have operators for that:

- `zsh`:

  ```
    a[1,0]=newvalue
  ```

(also works for prepending strings to scalar variables)

- `yash`:

  ```
    array -i a 0 newvalue
  ```

Comment: "arrays in bash (copied from ksh) are rather associative arrays" ??

 I thought there are "regular" (tho possibly sparse) and associative (where you can use strings as indecies) arrays in bash, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
# array declaration  
arr=()  

#Function to read data from file a and add into array  
fun_add_in_array()
{  
input=$1  
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2  
do  
    echo "Element1 : $f1"  
    echo "Element2 : $f2"  
    arr+=( "$f1" )  
done < "$input"  
}  

#Function to print a array  
fun_read_array()  
{  
arr=("$@")  
for i in "${arr[@]}"  
do  
    echo $i  
done  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create an Indexed Array:**

```
$ declare -a A
$ declare -p A
```

> declare -a A

**Add some elements to the array:**

```
$ A+=(foo)
$ A+=(bar)
$ A+=("baz quux")
$ declare -p A
```

> declare -a A=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz quux")

**Remove the middle element, making it a Sparse Indexed array:**

```
$ unset A[1]
$ declare -p A
```

> declare -a A=([0]="foo" [2]="baz quux")

**Remove the last element from the Sparse Indexed Array:**

```
$ unset A[-1]
$ declare -p A
```

> declare -a A=([0]="foo")