# Why isn't $ARRAY+=$var working for me?

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

I am trying to add an element to a bash array. I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328882/how-to-add-remove-an-element-to-from-the-array-in-bash) question and tried to follow its advice.

This is my code:

```
selected_projects=()
for project_num in ${project_numbers[@]}; do
  selected_project=${projects[$project_num]}
  echo "selected project: $project_num $selected_project"
  $selected_projects+="$selected_project"
done
```

When I do this, I get an error:

> line 88: +=someProject: command not found

I tried many different alternatives to that line with lots of parenthesis and dollar signs, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong and what it should be. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `selected_projects+="$selected_project"` instead of `$selected_projects+="$selected_project"`

Comment: @MichalH This worked! Please leave this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That really is funny!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
selected_projects+="$selected_project"
```

instead of

```
$selected_projects+="$selected_project
```

Variable assignment in bash never contains `$` at the beginning of variable name.

Answer (score 3):

```
selected_projects=()
$selected_projects+="$selected_project"
```

Variable assignments in the shell don't use the `$` sign on the left hand side, it's only used when the value of the variable is expanded. This includes appending with `+=`. Your other assignment was correct.

In addition, since you've initialized `selected_projects` as an array, you probably want to use it such. To append a value to an array, you need to use the parenthesis in the appending assignment too. So, this would add a new element to `selected_projects`:

```
selected_projects+=("$selected_project")
```

Without the parenthesis, the assignment works like an unindexed reference to the array: it accesses the element with index `0`. E.g. this prints `foobar foobar`:

```
a=(); a+=foo; a+=bar; echo ${a[0]} $a
```