# Bash array arent adding elements to last

Tags: bash, variable, array, for

```
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# array=()
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# for i in 1 2 3 4
> do
> array+=($i)
> done
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# echo $array
1
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# for i in 1 2 3 4; do array+=( $i ); done
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# echo $array
1
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# for i in 1 2 3 4; do array+=( $i ); done
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# for i in 1 2 3 4; do
> array=( "${array[@]}" "$i" )
> done
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch# echo $array
1
root@kali-linux:~/Softwares/Softwares/Tools/dirsearch#
```

[How to add/remove an element to/from the array in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328882/how-to-add-remove-an-element-to-from-the-array-in-bash) I tried to add like as said in this question still it doesnt work and print 1

Comment: Declare -a also doest work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is fine (except that you forgot to quote `$i`), the problem is in your `echo $array`, which doesn't print all the elements of the array in `bash`.

`bash` has copied the awkward array design of `ksh` instead of that of `zsh`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `rc`...

In ksh, `$array` is short for `${array[0]}` (expands to the contents of the element of indice 0 or an empty string if it's not set).

To expand to all the elements of the array, you need:

```
$ printf ' - "%s"\n' "${array[@]}"
 - "1"
 - "2"
 - "3"
 - "4"
```

For the first element of the array (which may not be the one with indice 0 as ksh/bash arrays are sparse):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]:0:1}"
1
```

And for the element of indice 0 (which in your example is going to be the same as the first element):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$array"
1
```

or:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[0]}"
1
```

To print the definition of a variable, you can also use `typeset -p`:

```
ksh93u+$ typeset -p array
typeset -a array=( 1 2 3 4 )
```

```
bash-5.0$ typeset -p array
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")
bash-5.0$ unset 'array[0]'
bash-5.0$ typeset -p array
declare -a array=([1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")
bash-5.0$ printf '%s\n' "$array"

bash-5.0$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]:0:1}"
2
```

Comment: Can you show how to make a array containing (0 1 2 3 4) from for loop when array is empty at first @Stephane Chazelas

Comment: @DipeshSunrait, see edit.

Comment: still it doesnt work : https://imgur.com/a/PgXMnet i have quoted both array and i

Comment: @DipeshSunrait, try reading my answer again (maybe after refreshing the page). The problem is with your `echo $array`, not with your loop.

Comment: OH I FORGOT THAT ITS PRINTING FIRST CHARACTER

Comment: THANKS BRO GOT IT

Comment: Also bro how to solve this problem. My array becomes empty  after leaving a loop https://imgur.com/a/nypSE26 @StephaneChazelas

Comment: @DipeshSunrait, check [the bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)