# IFS not working

Tags: bash

Why is $PARTS blank

```
DIR=/Users/ishandutta2007/Projects/yo
IFS='/' read -ra PARTS <<< "$DIR"
echo $PARTS
```

Edit: Thanks for suggesting alternate ways, but I am looking to fix the issue with IFS

Comment: same [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594987/72456), answers your question as well.

Comment: Using `read` is also wrong for arbitrary  paths as `read` only considers the first line of the path. Also note that `/a/b/` is split into "", "a" and "b" while `/a/b//` is split into "", "a", "b" and "" (in `bash` note that other shells use `read -A array` to read into an array).

Answer (score 4):

The array is not blank, `$PARTS` expands to the first element of the array which happens to be empty and is the same as `${PARTS[0]}`:

```
$ declare -p PARTS
declare -a PARTS=([0]="" [1]="Users" [2]="ishandutta2007" [3]="Projects" [4]="yo")
```

To print all array elements as separate words use `"${PARTS[@]}"`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${PARTS[@]}"

Users
ishandutta2007
Projects
yo
```

To get the last element you can use a negative index:

```
$ echo "${PARTS[-1]}"
yo
```

---

But it's easier to get the last element using a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ echo "${DIR##*/}"
yo
```

This removes the longest prefix pattern `*/` from `DIR`.

Comment: Very good.  There are also others way to get the base name.  The pros and cons of different methods are discussed in ["dirname and basename vs parameter expansion"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253524/dirname-and-basename-vs-parameter-expansion)