# Multiply element of bash array and set array element to the new value

Tags: bash, array

In bash, if an element in an array is found to contain a `K`, I want to multiply that element by 1000 and set that element to the product.

```
for i in "${stats_array[@]}"
do
        if echo "$i" | grep -q K; then
                # set that value to that value times 1000
        fi
done
```

How is this accomplished in a bash script?

My array might look like:

```
stats_array: 1, 54, 54K, 99
```

And I want it to look like:

```
stats_array: 1, 54, 54000, 99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ { IFS=, ; arr=( 1,54,54K,99k ); }

$ printf '%s\n' ${arr[@]}
1    
54    
54K    
99k

## note: enable extended pattern matching for [...] with 'shopt -s extglob'
$ rearr=( "${arr[@]//%[Kk]/000}" )
$ printf '%s\n' ${rearr[@]}
1    
54    
54000    
99000

## or write the changes to same array
$ arr=( "${arr[@]//%[Kk]/000}" )
```

---

See also: [How to add/remove an element to/from the array in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328882/72456)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the *indices* of the array so it's easy to set the new value.

This uses `case` to branch on glob patterns, and you can see it's easy to extend this to `M` and `G`

```bsh
stats_array=( 1 54 54K 99 )
for idx in "${!stats_array[@]}"; do
  value=${stats_array[idx]};
  case $value in
    *K) stats_array[idx]=$(( ${value%K} * 10**3 )) ;;
  esac
done
declare -p stats_array
```

```
declare -a stats_array=([0]="1" [1]="54" [2]="54000" [3]="99")
```

Note that bash arithmetic cannot handle floats, so you can't expect `53.9K` to turn into `53900`